# Java entering an if statement that is false

Tags: java, if-statement, netbeans-7

I'm running into the strangest error in this program, which is confirmed when debugging it. I have the following code (boiled down to highlight the problem, of course):

### `BHFrame.java`

```
public class BHFrame
{
  private boolean uSS;
  private StateSaver stateSaver;

  public BHFrame(boolean useInternalStateSaver)
  {
    //Init code

    uSS = useInternalStateSaver;

    //More init code
    System.out.println(uSS);
    if (uSS)
    {System.out.println("Entered 1");
      stateSaver = new StateSaver(title, false);
      stateSaver.addSaveable(getThis());
    }

    //More init code
    System.out.println(uSS);
    if (uSS)
    {System.out.println("Entered 2");
      try
      {
        stateSaver.loadState();
        stateSaver.putState(getThis());
      }
      catch (IOException ex)
      {
        alertUserOfException(ex);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### `GUI.java`

```
public class GUI extends BHFrame
{
  public GUI(boolean useInternalStateSaver)
  {
    super(useInternalStateSaver);
  }
}
```

### `Main.java`

```
public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    GUI gui = new GUI(false);
  }
}
```

### Output

```
false
false
Entered 2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at bht.tools.comps.BHFrame.<init>(BHFrame.java:26)
    at bhms.GUI.<init>(GUI.java:5)
    at bhms.Main.main(Main.java:5)
```

The class `BHFrame` is extended and run from a child class that calls this constructor, but that really shouldn't affect this behavior. The problem is that, when `false` is passed to the constructor as `useInternalStateSaver`, the first `if (uSS)` is skipped, but the second is entered. Upon debugging, I found that `uSS` is `false` throughout runtime, including on the line of the second `if` statement, here. **Why would Java enter an `if` statement when the condition returns `false`?** Before you ask, I did delete the `.class` files and recompile it just in case there was some residual code messing with it, but I got the same result. And rest assured, all the references to the `uSS` variable are displayed here.

### Solution

---

As it turns out, this appears to be a bug in NetBeans 7.1 Build 201109252201, wherein the IDE doesn't properly insert new code into the compiled `.class` files. The problem was fixed by compiling the files externally. A [bug report](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=204605) has been submitted.

Comment: `if` condition won't make wrong decisions. your variable `uSS` must become true in your `//More init code` line.

Comment: It isn't. Something else is going on.

Comment: Could you add in the code that occurs at the `//More init code` part?

Comment: I think my latest edit shows that it's not what's going on there. Plus, the `//More init code` part doesn't interact with the `uSS` variable.

Comment: I'm sure uSS must be changed at some point in your code. It is not the problem with JVM or java compiler. Since you have done the debugging, you should have found out where it has become true yourself.

Comment: What happens if you print `uSS` at the beginning of the inside of your `try{}` block?

Comment: Look, I confirmed with the debugger that `uSS` is always `false`. It is never `true`, not even when entering the second `if` block

Comment: Can you format the code using netbean format function? just to make sure that your braces are correct.

Comment: I... did? My NetBeans formatting preferences are reflected perfectly int he provided code.

Comment: The code you're debugging and the code you posted are different (and the code you posted doesn't compile because of bits you've deleted) - so it's possible that the issue is due to that. Everyone is telling you're wrong, because there is no way the code you've shown us can do what you're saying it does. But maybe the code you're actually running can do that.

Comment: Please provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: @trashgod I'm trying, but people keep demanding more and more...

Comment: @Supuhstar most of those "demands" are coming about because of the lack of a SSCCE. But to be honest, I expect the answer you'll get after the SSCCE is going to be "works for me"

Comment: The art of the sscce is to provide less and less. When I comment out all the erroneous lines, I see nothing unexpected.

Comment: @trashgod I initially posted only what they needed: The code in BHFrame that interacts with `uSS`. However, they continually asked for the code I left out

Comment: What if you leave `uSS` unused and add a another private boolean and use that - what happens? And, if Java as optimizations, try turning them off if they're on? And what happens when the code is run outside of the debugger and outside of Netbeans?

Comment: Your example _isn't_ self contained. The issue is that none of us can take the code, compile it, and reproduce the problem. I understand why you can't do that, but it also means that we can't actually help you. Your code looks fine, but it's incomplete (so we keep assuming the issue is in the code that we can't see) and it isn't standalone (so we can't see the issue for ourselves). Your best bet it to keep reducing it down until you get a piece of code that exhibits the issue, and only contains methods that you can post. Anything else is likely to keep going round in the same circles.

Comment: @Zabba +1 for the first constructive comment I've seen, here

Comment: @Tim why can't you give a list of possible reasons that this can happen, eliminate all the ones that have to do with things I said I took care of (like changing the value of `uSS` somewhere), and posting the rest?

Comment: This may be stupid but try stable version of Netbeans. SInce none of us can see the problem, we can only make assumption for you to try.

Comment: Also try printing the value of `useInternalStateSaver` along side the value of `uSS` you are already printing. And also try using `useInternalStateSaver` directly instead of assigning to `uSS` and using that (set the uSS at the end of the method instead of near the beginning)

Comment: @gigadot Thank you for your idea. I am now downloading the last stable release.

Comment: You could also try using a different version of the JDK than what you're using now (try 1.7 and 1.5 if you're using 1.6 for example)

Comment: Another suggestion is that if you delete the class files yourself using windows explorer, can you try to use Netbean clean function to clean it and you should try to restart your Netbeans. (if the problem disappear, it maybe the bug in Netbeans)

Comment: @Zabba Post "what happens when the code is run outside of the debugger and outside of Netbeans?" as an answer, because it runs fine outside NetBeans

Comment: Also, how is it that `GUI gui = new GUI(false);` is not giving an error (unless you do have a ctor with one parameter as well). Could it be that that other ctor is calling the `BHFrame` ctor too - and thus the code is running from a different entry point than what you are thinking it is?

Comment: @Zabba sorry, I never updated the Main.java code... look again

Answer (score 1):

Whatever's throwing that exception is probably ***not*** in your posted code.

It's not being caught by your `catch` statement, which only catches IOException.

It's a NullPointerException and can occur anywhere.

You have shown no indication that the code inside your `if` block is actually executing.  In your screenshot, there is absolutely know way of knowing if your `if` block is entered or not.  There are no logging statements.

Add debugging messages at various points to see exactly what is happening.  Or, you know, look at line 26 (wayyyyy before your posted code) to see why you're getting a NullPointerException.

Comment: but it shouldn't have entered the if statement in the first place. Since "Enter 2" text is printed, it means the block is executed.

Comment: +1 just for pointing out that the screenshot proves the code doesn't match the error output

Comment: Another edit adds a screenshot with the output after debugging to the next line from the first screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I've seen crazy stuff like this when there is bad RAM on the machine.  You might want to run memtest86.

You might also consider deleting all of your project class files, and then doing a build. Maybe you changed Main.java, but it was never recompiled. I hate that when that happens.

Comment: I states int he question that I deleted all my `.class` files, and why would bad RAM affect this one `boolean` value, but leave the rest of the 4294967288 bytes perfectly fine? And even if it is the case, wouldn't that mean that it would run fine the next time, as `uSS` will be stored in a different address?

Comment: If you don't think its the RAM, then what other explanation do you have for this apparent non-deterministic behavior? I was responsible for a project that saw 15,000 JVMs deployed across the country. There were machines that we would deploy to where the JVM would not behave correctly, where other software appeared to. After replacing the RAM on these machines, the problems went away. Memtest86 is free so there is no cost in trying it. The only other option is that you're doing something wrong, and you're not aware of what that is.

Comment: please don't post such comments without reading the full question (which includes the reason) and accepted answer

Comment: Yeah, I saw the answer up there after responding. I didn't know that it could be added like that. Wasn't sure if I should have deleted my comment or not. i.e. don't know the site's etiquette.

Comment: The best thing to do in that case would be to add another comment that retracts what you want to retract, so that any legitimate usable information you posted is still there to be learned.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, and sorry I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, because I can't see the code you are mentioning, but I reckon you have defined a local variable `uSS` in the second `//More init code` segment.

Once you define a *local* variable named the same as an *instance* variable, it 'hides' the instance variable. Better to qualify all instance variables with `this`.

So, try qualifying all above accesses of `uSS` with `this.` ... (`this.uSS`)

*Even if this isn't the issue, it might be better to post the full code anyway.*

HTH

Comment: Also, it would be good to mark the instance variable as `final`. It seems like it ought to be. Again, this would provide clarity if not anything else

Comment: see edit; there is a screenshot showing that what I claim is really what is happening. I am no novice programmer; I know when I make variables what they do (that's why the class variable `uSS` isn't called `useInternalStateSaver`: to guarantee I'm referencing the right variable)

Comment: Also, I am hesitant to post the full code, as it is not only copyrighted, but also very extensive. I will if I get enough demand, but I guarantee you that this is all you need to see.

Comment: ok, but for clarity it's better to post code with qualified accessors and final variables where appropriate. It helps people to help you ..

Comment: I've posted as much as I'm comfortable with

Comment: That's really good, but (I know I'm repeating myself) you still haven't qualified your accessors or marked your instance variable as private. i.e. `if(this.uSS) {` and `private final boolean uSS;`. It may come to nothing but honestly it would remove several doubts for those who are trying to help you. I'm off now, good luck

Comment: p.s. I just upvoted your question, because clearly you're trying hard to engage with your [doubtful] audience. I see you found the solution too. Nice one

Comment: it came to nothing. As I mentioned before, I am no novice programmer, and `uSS` was never changed after it was first initialized, and I was referencing the same variable each time. However, it was not, as most respondents assumed, bad coding, but rather a bug in the IDE's debugger.

Comment: Dude I never meant to diss your prowess, so don't take offence from me - just trying to isolate some possibilities (although you took an onslaught from a few others!)

Comment: sorry, I am just used to this community respecting the information I provide for them, and was severely taken aback when most of the responses didn't trust my analysis of my own problem